# Sharepoint 2010 managed metadata via powershell: can't access some fields

Tags: 2010, powershell, metadata

I'm trying to learn about accessing/setting managed metadata fields using powershell (v2) in sharepoint 2010.

Based on various tutorials/forums I have the following minimal (not)working example:

```
$Main_Scope = Start-SPAssignment

$SiteAddress = "http://foo.com/sites/bar/"  
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $SiteAddress
$docLib = $SPWeb.lists["Final Reporting"]

$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $SPWeb.Site
$termStore = $taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore

$taxonomyField = $docLib.Fields["Document Type"]
$termSet = $termStore.GetTermSet($taxonomyField.TermSetId)

Stop-SPAssignment $Main_Scope
```

The $taxonomyField object is null and hence $termStore.GetTermSet fails with the error

```
Cannot convert argument "0" with value "", for "GetTermSet" to type "System.Guid"
```

---

Probably related issue:

Minimal example:

```
$SPFile = $SPWeb.GetFile($path)
$SPItem = $SPFile.Item
$SPItem.fields
```

this displays all of the single line of text fields without a problem, but errors out when it reaches the managed metadata fields with the following error:

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..
```

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to both Sharepoint and Powershell so if there is any more info you need to help answer the question let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I've managed to find a different way to access the Term Store, so the first issue is solved, although the second problem still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to access my managed metadata using the techniques outlined here:

http://ramblingsofamadcomputerguy.blogspot.com.au/search/label/TaxonomyFieldValue.PopulateFromLabelGuidPair

and here

http://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/sharepoint-2010-how-to-set-taxonomy-field-values-programmatically/

In terms of the specific problem outlined in my question, I needed to use a different method of accessing the list. Instead of:

```
$taxonomyField = $docLib.Fields["Document Type"]
```

I needed to use:

```
$taxonomyField = $SPItem.fields.getfield("Document Type")
```

So getting the fields from the *item* and not from the *library*.

I still don't know what was going on with the second problem, but it is irrelevant now that I can access the fields this way.